# google marketplace multiple client_id

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are trying to put an app on the marketplace which needs multiple client_ids

(The app is running on appengine standard with python 2.7)

- a client_id for the service_account with domain wide authority
- a client_id for the web application
- a client_id from an apps-script library

All client_ids use different scopes. I have combined all scopes and entered them on the marketplace SDK configuration.

When i deploy the app on a test domain, only the serviceaccount seems to be authorized.
When the user then access the webapplication he is presented a grant screen which we want to avoid.

The documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing?hl=fr seems to imply that multiple client_id's are possible.

How should i configure the marketplace app so that multiple client_ids are authorized?
Is there something special i should do on the credentials configuration page of the api-manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out all three client_id's were being authorized after all.

the days that i was testing this, it took very long for the authorization to take  effect.
At this time all scopes and clientid are authorized within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you implement the authorization using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing?hl=fr#configure_additional_services), Service accounts allow a Google Apps domain administrators to grant service accounts domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the domain. You can also read [Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=fr#delegatingauthority) documentation.

> Note: You can only use AppAssertionCredentials credential objects in applications that are running on Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine. If you need to run your application in other environments—for example, to test your application locally—you must detect this situation and use a different credential mechanism (see [Other](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=fr#jwtsample_py)). You can use the [application default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials?hl=fr) to simplify this process.

Hope this helps.